# PHP MySQL query not working using my DB class

Tags: php, mysql

I've set up a Database class, a User class and a UserTools class to interact with a MySQL database. It seems that my UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT commands are working find but I can't figure out what's going on with my SELECT statements. I'm only using mysql right not until I get everything working as I'd like, then I'll switch over to mysqli or PDO. But anyway, here's what I'm looking at....

DB class....

```
public function select($table, $where) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
        return $this->processRowSet($result, true);

    return $this->processRowSet($result);
}

public function processsRowSet($rowSet, $singleRow=false) {

    $resultArray = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowSet)) {
        array_push($resultArray, $row);
    }

    if ($single_row === true)
        return $resultArray[0];


    return $resultArray;
}
```

UserTools class

```
public function getUser($id) {
    $db = new DB();
    $result = $db->select('users', 'id = $id');

    return new User($result);
}
```

There seems to be an issue with how I'm processing the rows or something. I've followed similar setups with UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT and they seem to work fine but I don't know whats going on here.

If I call an instance of new UserTools(), then try to run the getUser() function, it's not returning anything the way it's set up. If I keep the result from being pushed through the User class constructor, it just returns a Reference Value, meaning that I'm not processing the rows properly.

I have a feeling I'm overlooking something stupid here so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `public function processs`<--:)

Comment: *"I'm only using mysql right not until I get everything working as I'd like, then I'll switch over to mysqli or PDO"* ~ why would anyone do that on purpose?

Comment: I suggest you run your development environment with `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your `php.ini` file. Simple syntax errors like this are easily identified. Checking database function return values for errors is useful too

Comment: Thanks Casimir. I knew I was overlooking something stupid! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start,

```
$result = $db->select('users', 'id = $id');
```

Should be

```
$result = $db->select('users', 'id = '.$id);
```

As Casimir mentioned, there's a typo in `public function processsRowSet`

I'd `echo $sql; die;` to check if the query is complete.

Comment: Thanks J A. I've tried this previously and it didn't work.

Comment: What is the echo/output of your $sql;

Comment: If I call getUser(1) to get the user with the ID of one, it's just returning an empty User class to me

Comment: Please place echo $sql; die; before $result = mysql_query($sql); and provide the output.

Comment: Here's the output

SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id

I'm assuming that means there's a problem with how it's interpreting the $id variable?

Comment: and if I went back and changed $db->select('users', 'id = '.$id);

the output actually puts out SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1

But if I run that output into my User class, it comes back as an empty object

Comment: Turns out there was a problem running it through my User class. I've fixed it now. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

In UserTools class: `'id = $id'` wouldn't parse in $id. Instead do `"id = {$id}"` or similar so that it can parse $id.

Comment: Tried this and it isn't working for me. It appears that fixing that spelling error helped but it's returning an empty object right now

Comment: Oh yeah. You also needed to fix the $sql so it'll parse using `{$table}` and `{$where}`. Also the if statement  in select() is missing curly braces.